# Z-Index Not Working for a Gallery

Tags: javascript, css

http://gomocloud.com/ambassadorhi/homebuilder/2015/testing/testing.html

What I am trying to do is to get both the Roof colors and the Siding colors to display when selected.

I have already assigned different z-index levels to each of the sections.  However, as you can see, the roof image goes back to it's default color when I select a new color for the siding of the house, even though I am clicking on an element with a higher z-index.

I have even tried switching from position:absolute to position:relative in the CSS code. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is a [`JSFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/FreddyBentsen/0xu7k13s).

Comment: Is the siding color the black outline along the house? How it would look to have "Roof colors and the siding colors to both display"?

Comment: No.  All you have to do is click the thumbnails in the example I posted.  Cypress, Light Maple, etc... 

Please look at the link before replying.

Comment: A fiddle and code of what u have done would be appreaciated

Comment: @FredBentsen I did look at the link, I've seen no way to make the roof disappear. I'm not sure what is siding is being hidden in your program. Please explain what the problem is, give an example. Don't make assumptions about others simply because you are not explaining the problem clearly. I don't see any siding that should be displayed behind a roof.

Comment: @FredBentsen I did notice that when selecting a color for the house the roof will change back to it's default color (maybe that's what you meant by disappear?). But that has nothing to do with the z-index (which would be something behind the roof). The house color and roof are not blocking each other.

Comment: The problem is how you are assigning based on a click, by changing the URL. This means when you click a link, it doesn't remember what was clicked before and each item is reverted to it's default states. This means you may want to use another approach, such as simply changing images using a JavaScript click event.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek  Here's my fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/FreddyBentsen/0xu7k13s/

Answer (score 0):

You are controlling both the roof and the sidings with the same input. In this case it means that when you click on a roof, the sidings will go to the default siding, and vice versa.

You are also not really doing anything with the Z-index. All the roofs have the value 10 and all the sidings have 20 (which doesn't matter since the roofs doesn't overlap with the sidings anyway).

If you want to use the Z-index to show and hide, you should make the active roofs Z-index higher than all the other roofs and do the same thing with the sidings.

For this to work you'd need 2 variables. One to control which roof is active, and one to control which siding is active. Right now you're only able to control one of the things at a time, and the other will default to which one is higher in the DOM tree.

Comment: Thanks... I'll try that.  Wish me luck.

Comment: How would I indicate that a certain selected link is active?  Is it a:active?

Also, how would I place a different variable for the siding images, as opposed to the roof images?

Comment: a:active will only show the latest click. If you want to show the active selection on both choices you'll need to add and remove a class on click events (like `.active`) and control that in your css. Regarding the variables I'd suggest you read up on the basics of JavaScript, and maybe check out jQuery for this specific case.